# Small image on top of larger image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the small grey box to be at the top left in front of the black box on the page. An image on top of an image. I want the grey box to be visible on top of the black box. I set top and left to zero, and I tried z-index to move the grey image above the black square, but nothing. It needs to be IE9 compatible:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/zrjttnu1/

```
.nav-toggle {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: -999px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 70px;
height: 55px;
float: left;
display: block;
margin: 0 -2em 1em 0;


 }
.nav-toggle:before {
color: #444; /* Edit this to change the icon color */
font-family: "responsivenav";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-size: 28px;
text-transform: none;
position: absolute;
content: url(img/menu2.gif);
text-indent: 0;
text-align: center;
line-height: 65px;
speak: none;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
.nav-toggle.active:before {
font-size: 24px;
content: url(img/menu3.gif);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could position your nav-toggle box absolute and set top: 0;

```
.nav-toggle {
    ...
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpyumsck/1/